# File upload disappears in Web File Manager

Tags: files

I am trying to upload files to our Web File Manager (in Drupal 6.31), and while everything seems to work fine the file does not appear in the directory list afterward. It does not exist on the server either.

I checked the permissions on the default WebFM folder, and it is 775. I am logged in as the first (super admin) user. I am not receiving any error messages. There are no available updates for Drupal Core or WebFM.

What could be going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you using chrome while uploading files on WF Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a critical bug of Web File Manager module that sates "files are being deleted while browsing WebFM with Chrome" (Considering that you have been using chrome to upload files your Web File Maanger)
For more reference please refer to [this](https://drupal.org/node/795952).